# What happens to K.E. in matter antimatter annihilation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy-conservation, antimatter

If I have two matter and antimatter particles, say an electron and a positron, each moving towards each other with a certain speed, they annihilate after the collision. Does the energy of the photons released also include the K.E. of the electrons, aside from their relativistic mass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The photons play a vital role in balancing out the momentum and kinetic energy.